# How do remove the "Ok" button in popup (PySimpleGUI)

Tags: pysimplegui

Typical popup:

```py
sg.Popup("This is a simple popup")
```

This will show an "Ok" button with my text which I don't want.
How can I remove this button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just provide the `button_type` argument like this:

```py
sg.Popup("This is a simple popup", button_type=5)
```

In PySimpleGUI there are 5 types of button configurations:

```
Yes, No: 1
Cancel: 2
Error: 3
Ok, cancel: 4
No button: 5
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be calling `popup_no_buttons` rather than changing the button_type parameter.  The documentation states that it's not meant to be used by users.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.popup_no_buttons('This is a popup without buttons')
```

If you do use it, it's recommended you use the "enum" values for that parameter so that if the numbering changes your code will continue to function.  That value is `sg.POPUP_BUTTONS_NO_BUTTONS`